# ipad/iphone droppable implementation - detecting element being touched

Tags: jquery, web-applications

I am trying to develop a drag/drop functionality that works on both desktop and touch devices such as ipad/iphone.

I have no issues implementing the 'dragging' by simply binding the `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events on a given DOM element.

What I am struggling with is how to implement the 'droppable' part. So in other words, how do I figure out on what DOM element was my draggable dropped 'over'??

You can assume the use of jQuery. However, I am NOT using jQueryUI - which currently doesn't work for touch events.

Comment: +1 great question, used it track users movement over pages mobile safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you're page is going to have a lot of DOM elements. So I would suggest marking those that may have something dropped on them by using an HTML5 data attribute, i.e. . Then, in your touchend event handler, get the dropped element's position in the document using a combination of jQuery's .offset() and .height() and .width(). Once you have that, cycle through the marked "dropReceiver" divs to get *their* position. You're then ready to test whether the position of the dropped element intersects with the position of one of the dropReceiver elements.

For example:
draggedElement.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
    var draggedX1 = $(this).offset().left;
    var draggedX2 = $(this).width() + draggedX1;
    var draggedY1 = $(this).offset().top;
    var draggedY2 = $(this).height() + draggedY1;

```
$('div[data-dropReceiver=true]').each(function(){
    var droppedX1 = $(this).offset().left;
    var droppedX2 = $(this).width() + droppedX1;
    var droppedY1 = $(this).offset().top;
    var droppedY2 = $(this).height() + droppedY1;

    if((draggedX1 > droppedX1 && draggedX1 < droppedX2 && draggedY1 > droppedY1 && draggedY1 < draggedY2) || (draggedX2 > droppedX1 && draggedX2 < droppedX2 && draggedY2 > droppedY1 && draggedY2 < draggedY2)){

        var dropReceiver = $(this);
        //do stuff with the dragged element and the element it was dropped on
        break;
    }
});
```

I'm pretty sure my lengthy if statement there is correct, but I might have made a typo or two so make sure you re-examine it if you find that this code isn't working.

Also, it's quite likely that the final solution you'll need to implement will be a bit more complex. If it's possible that the dragged element will overlap more than one possible dropReceiver, you can't simply break out of the .each() loop once you find an intersection. Instead, you're going to need to actually calculate *how much* of the elements are intersecting, and ultimately designate the true dropReceiver to be the one that has the greatest amount of intersection with the dragged element. However, the code I've provided above already gives you the tools you'll need to do this since it essentially provides the coordinates of the bounding rectangles of each element.

**EDIT - in response to OP's first comment on this answer**
It doesn't seem possible to have the dropReceivers fire a touch event. Even if you bind a touchstart event to them, it won't fire because the dragged element is not a child element of a dropReceiver (I assume), and it must have absolute positioning in order to be dragged. That means it will always be layered (like a higher z-index) above the dropReceivers. Thus, it will always be blocking the user's finger from actually touching the dropReceiver. And therefore the touchstart event will never fire on the dropReceiver.

HOWEVER, I do think there is an easier solution than what I came up with. A touch event on Mobile Safari includes the x and y coordinates of that touch. So rather than testing for the intersection of the dragged element and the dropReceiver, all you need to do is test if the touch point falls within the bounds of the dropReceiver, i.e.

```
if(touchpoint.x > droppedX1 && touchpoint.x < droppedX2 && touchpoint.y > droppedY1 && touchpoint.y < droppedY2){
   //you've found the dropped element
}
```

This is definitely a better solution, since it eliminates the more complex situation where the dragged element could be intersecting with two dropReceivers. Since you're testing the single touch point instead, that will always fall within the bounds of only a single dropReceiver, so no intersection area comparisons would need to be made.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Max. You are right, I am expecting to have a very few droppable targets. Your idea of testing if a point intersects with dom element would work; I would use it as a last resort though. My ideal solution would be for the droppable targets to fire out an event when a user's touch is on top of it. If this is not feasible, I will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to consider using jQueryUI for this, so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  You can resolve the touch event issue with using jQueryUI by using the [jQuery.ui.touch-punch plug-in](http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/), which maps mouse events to touch events.

Comment: I haven't used this plugin, and I generally don't user jQueryUI. But my understanding is that jQueryUI tends to be a fairly heavy library. While this doesn't matter on powerful, non-mobile browsers, mobile Safari's javascript engine is much slower. So it's possible that the aesthetics of the dragging wouldn't be nearly as smooth as a custom-made solution like the one I provided.

Comment: It's true - speed becomes an issue when you go from a powerful desktop to an old iPhone.  However, that's an issue with any web application.  Also, keep in mind that you don't have to include every piece of functionality in jQueryUI - just build the .js with the components you need and that will considerably cut it down to size and improve performance.  I've done this and have released web apps with heavy use of jQueryUI's draggable, droppable features and HTML5 animation..  slowness is noticable, but acceptable.

Comment: I am using knockoutJS and my application is designed be driven by making changes to my backend model, which in turn notifies the view that goes off an updates DOM elements. Because jQueryUI will always update the location of an element when being dragged directly (there is no way to disable that), it doesn't play well with what I have. Also my drag/drop requirements are very minimal and a custom solution should do. I am almost there anyway!

Comment: oh well, perhaps this is a better solution for others.